# Long integer to 16 character Hex for Google Reader sync

Tags: php, python

Python Code

```
h = "%s"%("0000000000000000%x"%(i&0xffffffffffffffff))[16:]
```

I'd like to know how this would be done in PHP.

The application is for google reader syncronization.
An initial sync list comes with numeric values, but the actual article id hex.

Example Long Integer = **8643979098044673995**

Example Google Reader Article ID = tag:google.com,2005:reader/item/**77f5953120daafcb**

Comment: just to highlight that these ids are signed (there are negative ids) - just a head-up because I've seen some people having problems with this

Answer (score 2):

```
sprintf("%016x", 8643979098044673995);
```